# Is there an established configuration file for running SubGit as an upstart service?

Tags: git, svn, upstart

It seems that upstart is the right way to shut things down and start them up during the reboot process, but I failed to find configuration files with a search of SubGit documentation and a general search of the web.

The start and stop commands in my case are as simple as follows, but both username and repo path depend on user installation:

```
sudo -u subgit subgit install /dev.git    # start
sudo -u subgit subgit uninstall /dev.git  # stop
```

I am about to implement a working copy of /etc/init/subgit.conf (not to be confused with SVN_REPOS/conf/subgit.conf in SubGit) and will post pending better answers.

Note: SubGit is a particular implementation of bridging Subversion and Git.

Answer (score 0):

Although the start command is simple, it calls a java program that seems to fork some number of times, causing upstart issues.  Fortunately, [johnjamesmiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494041/johnjamesmiller) posted [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12217085/527489) for this type of issue to StackOverflow.

While the following seems to provide upstart wrapper for the instance-parameterized subgit commands (allowing multiple repos to be run on the server), using an 'instance'-based job makes it impractical to have this start/stop automatically.  Instead, I have added start commands for my repos to /etc/rc.local (shown at bottom).

```
# subgit.conf - subgit job file

description "service for running SubGit mirroring"
author "Randy Sage"

# Note: because subgit forks too many times, normal upstart controls do not work
# Instead, use the method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12217085/527489

# Run with subgit/gitshare ids, since we use shared gitshare access to repos
setuid subgit
setgid gitshare

instance $repo

pre-start exec subgit install $repo  # actually start

script  # dummy process tracking java app
  while ps aux |  grep "java.*$repo" | grep -v grep >/dev/null ; do
    sleep 1
  done
end script

post-stop script
  if ps aux |  grep "java.*$repo" | grep -v grep >/dev/null ; then
    subgit shutdown $repo
  fi
end script
```

Here are the /etc/rc.local commands:

```
...
start subgit repo=/matlab.git
start subgit repo=/dev.git

exit 0
```

Note that services started this way appear under `initctl list`, but not `service --status-all`:

```
rsage@subgit:~$ initctl list | grep subgit
subgit (/dev.git) start/running, process 2974
subgit (/matlab.git) start/running, process 2507
```